# Using objectFilter with multiple conditions

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to remove invoice entries returned with in a date range and the invoiceTotalAmount isn't zero. I am using URL:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json?resultLimit=0,200&objectMask=mask[createDate,closedDate,typeCode,statusCode,invoiceTotalAmount,invoiceTopLevelItems[id,description,hostName,domainName,totalRecurringAmount,totalOneTimeAmount,parentId,categoryCode,billingItemId,billingItem[id,cancellationDate,createDate,hourlyFlag,lastBillDate,cancellationReason,orderItemId,orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord[username]]]]]]&objectFilter={"invoices":{"invoiceTotalAmount":{"operation":"!=0"},"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["7/29/2016 0:0:0"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["7/30/2016 23:59:59"]}]}}}
```

I am getting returned:

RC 500 msg "Internal Server Error" with content "{"error":"An error has occurred while processing your request.  Please try again later.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}'

Is there something wrong with the multiple objectFilters specification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce the error message when filtering `invoiceTotalAmount`:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?resultLimit=0,50&objectMask=mask[id,createDate,invoiceTotalAmount]&objectFilter={   "invoices": {     "invoiceTotalAmount": {       "operation": "!=0"     }   } }
```

The filter seems not to be working for that `relational property`. I suggest to open a SL ticket for this problem.